# Magento 2 What to update in existing CE to get RabbitMQ working

Tags: magento2.3.3, rabbit-mq

I have a few installations that slowly have been upgraded to 2.3.3 without RabbitMQ. Now I have added Rabbit but I am not sure I've covered all changes needed.

The `queue` config is added in `etc/env.php` and I see that Magento connects to Rabbit (creating topcis).

I've edited all of these files in the file system:

- `queue_consumer.xml`
- `queue.xml`
- `queue_publisher.xml`
- `queue_topology.xml`
- `communication.xml`

to use `amqp` instead of `magento-db`. Then the site is upgraded and redeployed.

I see some messages coming but fewer than I expected. For example I can't see messages when an order is created.

Did I miss anything? Something else I should change or is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was on the right path but also had to enable the cron runner for consumers. It looks like it is not added by default on an upgrade.

I added following to `app/etc/env.php` and did a redeploy (upgrade):

```php
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 10000,
        'consumers' => []
    ],
```

Comment: ...but the cron job is bork, the consumers are started over and over again even though there are consumers already running. I had to manage the workers manually to get this working properly.